# How to modify the Key of an Ordered Dictionary at Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, key, ordereddictionary

I am reading an excel file with around 2000 sheets with pandas. The excel sheet is loaded as an Ordered Dictionary since I have used the following:

```py
test = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

Let's assume that it looks like that:
[image: Ordered dictionary from excel file]

I would like to modify the name of the sheets and save the Ordered Dictionary to an excel file again. The names of the sheets are stored as the keys of the Ordered Dictionary, so basically I would like to just modify the keys and save to excel again.

As it can be noticed the name of the key ends with a year, i.e. 2020, 2022 etc. I would like all the keys to be modified such that they are reduced by 1, so the name of the keys are now 2019, 2021 etc. I would also like to make sure that the content does not change; meaning that the dataframe that used to assigned to A.AA.XX2020 is now assigned to A.AA.XX2019. The "General" sheets does not have to be modified.

Since there are many sheets in the excel file, I would prefer an automated procedure.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not for giving an order to someone to code your whole script.

Comment: @Vaiaro It was not my intension to make this post sound like this. It is just that I have loaded the excel file and then tried to change the keys by getting the keys with the .keys() command. However, nothing that I tried was working so I felt it did not make sense to put my trials here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope following will suit your needs:

```py
import pandas as pd

# read Excel file
test = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

# get keys from dict without 'General'
keys = list(test.keys())
keys.remove('General')

# iterate over keys
for key in keys:

    # get the old year
    year_old = int(key[-4:])

    # make the new year
    year_new = year_old - 1

    # create name for new key
    key_new = key[:-4] + str(year_new)

    # copy values from old key in new key and delete old key
    test[key_new] = test.pop(key)

# write dataframes from dict in one Excel file with new sheet names    
with pd.ExcelWriter('test_new.xlsx') as writer:
    for sheet_name, df in test.items():
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

Comment: Does it helped you?